# Send SMS messages from PC as if you were sending them by phone

Tags: php, sms

Hello everyone my question is very specific I'm not asking how to send sms for free, obviously it would not make sense, much less no method with gateway that many telephone companies have blocked as an anti spam method to date, but I'm asking for example through api di telegram it is possible through form php and json to send from the software a message that arrives to the recipients as if you had sent it by smartphone.

The question is: how can you send text messages with php, which connect to your tariff plan as if you were sending them by phone, thanks

Comment: You need to pay for access to an SMS gateway and use its API

Answer (score 0):

Although I think your question is quite ambiguous I'd suggest 2 possible ways depending on your priority.

1. If your main priority is using certain tariff plan (like using cheap SMS on certain simcards etc.) - your need to connect your simcard(s) to PC/server with GSM-modem or similar hardware. Then interact with it by COM-port etc. Also you may want to ask your GSM-carrier if you can use your tariff plan (simcard account) via some API but it's extremely low chances for positive reply. The API in most cases is not related to a simcard tariff plans but it do relates to some standalone Sms service.
2. If you main priority is the Number which your recipients may use for replies, you can look for SMS APIs with Virtual Long Number available. Many service providers allow to send SMS via API using VLN as alphanumeric sender name. This feature enables you to collect replies.